# JS: Separatedly get value from textareas with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say I have the following textareas

```
<textarea class='save'></textarea>
<textarea class='save'></textarea>
<textarea class='save'></textarea>
```

They all have the class 'save'. I want to write some jQuery/JavaScript that will get the text from within all the text areas with the 'save' class.

My code so far:

```
$('#getText').click(function(){
    var text = $('.save').text(); 
});
```

This will get ALL the text values and add them into the variable. However, I'd like to be able to iterate through each textarea first so I can edit it. My pseudo code would be like this:

```
On button 'click' -> Get first '.save', wrap it in <p></p>, then add a 
<h1>Title</h1>, append this to a variable/array.
```

I could then output it like this:

```
<h1>Text 1</h1>
<p>text from textarea 1</p>

<h1>Text 2</h1>
<p>text from textarea 2</p>

<h1>Text 3</h1>
<p>text from textarea 3</p>
```

Rinse and repeat for each '.save', any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery `each()` to iterate over each element you get with `$(".save")`

Then you can do what you need with it. In my example below, I created an array with the titles and each iteration of the `each()` I get a new title, add it to the `html` string and then I concat the value from the `textarea` that I'm currently iterating over, wrapped in a `<p>` tag.

```js
let titles = ["text 1", "text 2", "text 3"]
const result = $("#result")

$('#getText').click(function(){
    let html = ""
    var textAreas = $('.save')
    textAreas.each(function(idx) {    
      let txtAreaValue = this.value;
      let title = titles[idx];
      html += "<h2>" + title + "</h2>" 
      html += "<p>" + txtAreaValue + "</p>";
    })
    console.log(html);
    result.html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='save'></textarea>
<textarea class='save'></textarea>
<textarea class='save'></textarea>
<input type="button" value="get" id="getText"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```